# linear interpolation error

Tags: functions, fitting, linear-algebra, interpolation, data

I have two set of data for pressure and energy density and I used a linear interpolation to apply the data as a function in terms of each other.

```
fromPressureToEnergy = 
  Interpolation[Most@Transpose[{Pressure, EnergyDensity}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
fromEnergyToPressure = 
  Interpolation[Most@Transpose[{EnergyDensity, Pressure}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Then for some cases, I faced the error below.

`InterpolatingFunction::dprec: The precision of input value {3.60289*10^16} and/or the interpolation grid is insufficient to compute the value.`

Could you please help me that how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Without an (simple!) example we can not help you.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2082581).

Comment: Due to my little knowledge in Mathematica, I guessed that this is a common error for linear interpolation. I do not know how I can give an example since this part is a small part of code in which I have a Runge-kutta forth order that solves a differential equation for pressure that energy density is a variable of that differential equation. for each step of Runge-kutta calculation, the interpolation will be applied to find the corresponding energy density

Comment: It has to do with the numerics of the data passed to `Interpolation`, probably.  We don't know what that data is. You can look up the error message in documentation center, ref/message/InterpolatingFunction/dprec -- I doubt it has anything to do with the interpolation order.